# CRUD Methods is not activated telerik scheduler asp.net MVC core

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-core-mvc, scheduler

I'm using Telerik Scheduler asp.net MVC Core UI Controller. I have a problem with the following methods `Date_Grouping_Read`, `Date_Grouping_Destroy`, `Date_Grouping_Create` and `Date_Grouping_Update`. They are not firing when I try to update or create meeting?

```
//HomeController 
namespace TelerikScheduler.Controllers
{
public partial class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMeetingData meetingData;

    public HomeController(IMeetingData meetingData)
    {
        this.meetingData = meetingData;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new HomePageViewModel();
        model.Rooms = meetingData.GetAll();


        return View(model);
    }




    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var model = meetingData.Get(id);
        if (model == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public virtual JsonResult Date_Grouping_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(meetingData.GetAll().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    public virtual JsonResult Date_Grouping_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Meeting meeting)
    {
        meetingData.delete(meeting);
        return Json(new[] { meeting }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    public virtual JsonResult Date_Grouping_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Meeting meeting)
    {
        meetingData.Insert(meeting);

        return Json(new[] { meeting }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    public virtual JsonResult Date_Grouping_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Meeting meeting)
    {
        meetingData.Update(meeting);
        return Json(new[] { meeting }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
}
```

}

View

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Meeting>().Name("Meeting").Date(new DateTime(2017, 5, 13))
      .StartTime(new DateTime(2017, 5,13, 7, 00, 00))
      .Views(views=>{
          views.DayView();
          views.AgendaView();
      })
      .Height(600)
      .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
      .Group(group => { group.Resources("Rooms"); group.Date(true); })
      .Resources(resource =>
      {
          resource.Add(m => m.RoomId).Title("Room").Name("Rooms").DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value").DataColorField("Color").BindTo(new[] {
              new { Text = "Meeting Room 101", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" },
              new { Text = "Meeting Room 201", Value = 2, Color = "#f58a8a" }
          });
          resource.Add(m => m.Attendees)
              .Title("Attendees")
              .Multiple(true)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .DataColorField("Color")
              .BindTo(new[] {
                  new { Text = "Alex", Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,
                  new { Text = "Bob", Value = 2, Color = "#51a0ed" } ,
                  new { Text = "Charlie", Value = 3, Color = "#56ca85" }
              });
      }).DataSource(d => d
          .Model(m =>
          {
              m.Id(f => f.RecordId);
              m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
              m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
          })
          .Read("Date_Grouping_Read", "Scheduler")
          .Create("Date_Grouping_Create", "Scheduler")
          .Destroy("Date_Grouping_Destroy", "Scheduler")
          .Update("Date_Grouping_Update", "Scheduler")
          )
          .BindTo(Model.Rooms).Deferred())


@section scripts {
    @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts();

}
```

Comment: Title is bound 2 times, in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they won't fire when the control is setup for the wrong Controller...

```
      .Read("Date_Grouping_Read", "Scheduler")
      .Create("Date_Grouping_Create", "Scheduler")
      .Destroy("Date_Grouping_Destroy", "Scheduler")
      .Update("Date_Grouping_Update", "Scheduler")
```

All show `Scheduler` when since you have posted code for `Home` should be

```
      .Read("Date_Grouping_Read", "Home")
      .Create("Date_Grouping_Create", "Home")
      .Destroy("Date_Grouping_Destroy", "Home")
      .Update("Date_Grouping_Update", "Home")
```